# Performing Segue takes too long

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uitableview, segue

I receive data async via a completion method.
When the completion get fired, I passing the data to a new `tableviewcontroller`.

But the table view controller takes too much time to load. The data is an array with up to 25 objects. So not that much.

To move to the new controller, I use a segue I created in `storyboard`.

This is the completion method:

```
{
    if(receivedArray != nil)
    {
        searchResult = receivedArray;
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"searchToDisplay" sender:self];
    }
}
```

When I debug, and set a breakpoint to the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method, I get there after less than one second.

here the method:

```
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"searchToDisplay"])
{
    BookingDisplayTableViewController *bookingVC = (BookingDisplayTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    bookingVC.bookings = [NSArray arrayWithArray:searchResult];

}
```

Additionally here the viewDidLoad method of the BookingDisplayController. The viewWillAppear isn't overrided.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"BookingCellDesign" bundle:nil];
    [self.tableView registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"BookingCell"];

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tableBackground.png"]];

    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
}
```

And I can't get the performance problem here...

I need help. :)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

So i troubleshooted the problem. It was the completion method.

I got the date via dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)... And a synchronous NSMutableRequest.

I fired the completion After I send the synchronous request. Now I put this code inside the dispath block

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
^{
   if(response)
   {
       [self removeLoadingView];
       if(bookingTemp.count > 0)
           completion(bookingTemp);
       else
           completion(nil);
   }
```

});

And now it works great.

What I don't understand before I did this, I debugged and reached the completion block like now. But only the segue didn't start.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please show some code from 'BookingDisplayTableViewController', especially from the 'viewWillXXX' methods in case they are implemented.

Comment: I updated the question. The BookingCell is a custom cell with 6 Labels and 2 Switches..

Comment: How long does it take to get to the end of 'viewDidLoad'?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the backgroundcolor/image? If the image is large/complex perhaps that is causing your delay

Comment: Yes. And I changed the custom cell too.

Comment: I think without more code/info we are only able to guess the problem. Is this just a test project for you so that you could host the project somewhere and we can get an insight into the project without requesting code snippets piece by piece? After the problem is found we can edit the question accordingly to provide the solution for future reference.

Comment: I found the mistake. See the start post. Thanks for help guys!